# Convert a string to a new string according to its character content

Tags: java

My purpose in this code was to check if the string has the same characters, and print ")" instead, and in the opposite case,"(". I assume that using for each inside for loop is a critical error, and although it still doesn't function properly.

```
static String encode(String word){
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char [] chars = word.toCharArray();    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i<chars.length; i++){
        for (char single : chars) {
        if (single!=chars[i]) {
             sb.append("(");
         } else {
             sb.append(")");
         }
    }   
}
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what the goal is, can you give some sample inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: The outer loop is iterating over all the characters (by index), and the inner loop is also iterating over all the characters (by value). Which means that if the input to 10 characters, the `if` statement is executed 10 * 10 = 100 times. Is that really what you intended?